# Distribution of bivariate normal conditioned with <=

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, bivariate

As part of solving a bigger problem (for the multi-variate case), I am focusing first on the bi-variate case:

Given two dependent normal variables $P_1$ and $P_2$, I have two questions:

1. Does the conditional probability $f_{x|P_2 \leq t}(x)$, with fixed (constant) $t$ follow a uni-variate normal distribution?
2. If yes, how can I compute the mean and std-dev for that normal distribution?
3. If not, can I either compute $f_{x|P_2 \leq t}(x)$ or its CDF $Pr[P_1 \leq x | P_2 \leq t]$ analytically?

In case it helps, we may define $P_1 = A_1 + A_2$ and $P_2 = A_1 + A_3$, where $A_1$, $A_2$ and $A_3$ are independent normal variables.

Comment: It certainly isn't the case  that the *probability* you ask about in 1 follows a normal distribution - the probability will be a constant given $t$ and $X$ (as it happens, it also isn't the case that the conditional distribution of the random variable is normal). Also if you're going to avoid the usual notational conventions (which would be upper case letters for random variables - so $P_1$ rather than $p_1$ and lower case letters for constants  - so $x$ rather than $X$), you had better define all your symbols (i.e. please define $X$)

Comment: Hi Glen, sorry for the notation bugs. I am more of an applied Mathematician. I corrected and hope it makes more sense now.